# Making checkbox size bigger in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to increase the size of checkbox in MS Access and I know that the default checkbox size cannot be increased.

However, I tried to achieve this by creating an input box and following what is listed here:

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-52.html

I am confused about this step:

```
Hold down the Alt key, and type 0168 on the numeric keypad (the character for False)
```

Holding alt key and typing that does not give me a "X" in report view. It gives a very small question mark.

Can I no longer use the method described in the blog above to create a bigger checkbox?

Comment: I am using Access 2010. Works for me. Shows either a square with a check or a blank square. If you want an "X" then don't use WingDings characters in format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technique from that blog is simply setting format on a numeric value where character shown depends on whether number is positive or negative. First position is for positive number and second position is for negative. Since True is -1 in a Yes/No field, second position character will be displayed.

If Alt+ is too difficult or other symbols are preferred, another way to get special characters is to copy/paste from Windows Character Map utility.

Instead of using Wingdings font to display symbols, can show alpha characters by setting Format property of textbox with:

To show Y or N: `\N;\Y`

To show X or nothing: `;\X`

Same result can be achieved with an IIf() conditional expression in textbox ControlSource or query calculated field. Difference is the calculated result is the alpha character whereas setting format property does not alter what is actually in the field/textbox.